# Remember control's text while being disabled

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the best way to remember Text/Value of a control after it is enabled again?

In my special case I have a checkbox to enable/disable a NumericSpinBox.

When checkbox is switched to Checked=false: spinbox is disabled and the last value (e.g. 10) should be remembered and the text should be cleared.

When checkbox is switched to Checked=true: spinbox is enabled again and the remembered value (e.g. 10) is reassigned.

Ok, I could store the value in an extra field of my form or container control. But if there are several controls with remembering values the additional fields are too much overhead (in terms of readability) for so small feature IMO. 
So I hope you have better solutions.

Comment: Your's and Amen's answers are my favorites up to now. I want to wait by tomorrow whether there are more alternatives before I will accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store value in the Tag property of the numericbox or checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Define a Type that represent the fields that you want and create an object of that type that hold all the state of your UI element. Set the value manually on enable or use binding